# Excel VBA - Worksheet_Calculate() - error when ever the data is updated manually in the source sheet

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel VBA - `worksheet_calculate` procedure is written to change the color of the shapes based on the values in the respective cells exists same sheet which are vlookuped from another sheet in the same workbook.

List Box(Form Control) is used for multiple column data.

The code works fine for existing data.

Whenever the source values are keyed in manually, the VBA throws up the error

[image: screenshot]

#### code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim Target As Range
    Set Target = Range("T6:T35")
    Dim v1 As Integer
    Dim v2 As Integer
    Dim s As Integer
    Dim t As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Shapename As String
    If Intersect(Target, Range("T6:T35")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        v1 = Left(Range("N6"), 2)
        v2 = Right(Range("N6"), 2)
        s = 19
        t = 20
        For i = 6 To 35
            Shapename = Cells(i, s)
            If Cells(i, t) < Range("N5") Then
                ActiveSheet.Shapes(Shapename).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
            ElseIf Cells(i, t) >= v1 And Cells(i, t) < v2 Then
                ActiveSheet.Shapes(Shapename).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbYellow
            ElseIf Cells(i, t) >= Range("N7") Then
                ActiveSheet.Shapes(Shapename).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
            End If
        Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not 100% clear of what is happening in this code, but it tries to change the colour of shape in the currently **active** sheet. See if removing `ActiveSheet.` before `Shapes(Shapename...` makes any difference.

Comment: Thank you JK2017 for looking into the code. The source data is located in another sheet in the same work book. the users will update the values manually. the data is v lookup in to another sheet where there are shapes. There are multiple columns in source sheet, hence form control is used to select different column data in the sheet where there are shapes. Based on the selected column header in the form control, the data is vlookuped. The color of the shapes has to be changed based on the updated values.

Comment: The code works fine for existing data, when ever the new data is entered in the source sheet, excel throws up the error.

Comment: After removing Activesheet. the code is working fine. The code was written in the sheet where the worksheet_calculate() event is to be triggered. Hence it was showing an error. Anyways thank you again @JK2017